# get all unique records and their corresponding column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Is it possible to get all unique records as well as their corresponding column in a database?

something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM table_name
?where?
```

I want to get all unique records with their corresponding column.

I tried:

```
SELECT distinct(column_name), other_column
FROM table_name
?where?
```

I still get duplicate records.

I tried:

```
SELECT distinct(column_name)
    FROM table_name
    ?where?
```

I get unique records but incomplete column. How can I get all unique records w/ their column?

Comment: Do you want each unique row or each unique value somewhere in the table? e.g. if you have a table with row 1 = 1, a, 11/21/2013; row 2 = 2, a, 11/22/2013 do you want the result to return 1, 2, a, 11/21/2013, 11/22/2013 with their corresponding column names?

Comment: let's say the column are as follows: (pk, fk_id, name, date). I have row1 = 1, 1, a, 2010; row2 = 2, 2, b, 2010; row3 = 3, 1, a, 2011; I want the output to be row1 = 1, 1, a ,2010; row2= 2, 2, b, 2010.

Comment: I think something like that. Can I see your logic? I want to try it. Is it also possible to return 1,a,11/21/2013 in every record of the second column which is a?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM
(
  SELECT MIN(pk_id) pk_id
    FROM table_name
   GROUP BY fk_id
) q JOIN table_name t
    ON q.pk_id = t.pk_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a3ff/1)** demo

In Postgres you can use `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fk_id) t.*
  FROM table_name t
 ORDER BY fk_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1306f/2)** demo

Comment: @xyxy Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?