# django queryset - mysql : how to get distinct item w.r.t two columns

Tags: mysql, django

I have table as

Model name: `Test`

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 .....
1   A   1
2   A   1
3   A   3
4   B   1
5   B   1
6   B   4
7   D   2
8   D   3
9   D   3
10  F   3
11  B   4
```

I want to get all the rows with unique combination of col1 and col2 and the row with recent id

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 .....
11  B   4
10  F   3
9   D   3
7   D   2
5   B   1
3   A   3
2   A   1
```

How can i get this

i tried

```
Test.objects.all().order_by('-id').distinct('col1','col2')
```

But it says `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`

Comment: group by vol1 and col2 and select max from id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `annotate` on the queryset to make a group by query like below:

```py
from django.db.models import Max, Subquery

grouping_query = Test.objects.values('col1', 'col2').annotate(Max('id'))

print(grouping_query.query) # prints the sql query that gets executed
```

This will return the `max` of the `id` column for the `col1`-`col2` combination.

Then use this in a subquery on `Test` model to get the other fields `col3`, `col4` etc. like below:

```py
Test.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(grouping_query.values('id__max')))
```

Comment: can i see all the columns in that row with max(id)

Comment: The queryset returns the following fields - col1, col2, and id__max (for the max(id)), updated the answer

Comment: Updated answer, if there are other columns col3, col4 etc

Comment: Using raw sql, this could have also been done using join. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20135500/2897115

Comment: Also how to add a limit to `grouping_query` eg: `Subquery(grouping_query.values('id__max')[:10]`. When i tried it gives error `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`

Comment: looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41116693/2897115 answers it. and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26520278/2897115